# Replace String in content

Tags: reactjs, events, replace, chat

Take a look on my **Chat.js** contents:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Chat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
      message: ""
    };
  }
  submitMessage(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(state => ({
      messages: [<li>{this.state.message}</li>, ...state.messages]
    }));
    this.setState({
      message: ""
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div class="container py-3">
          <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Simple Chat</h2>
          <form
            onSubmit={e => {
              this.submitMessage(e);
            }}
          >
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder={"Enter your message..."}
              value={this.state.message}
              onChange={e => this.setState({ message: e.target.value })}
            />
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success mt-2">
              Send Message
            </button>
          </form>

          <div className="container border mt-2">
            <ul className="group-list mt-3 pt-2">{this.state.messages}</ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

Also, this is my **example**:
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-water-1e8uq

i need to replace user link when anyone type username with **@**

for example, this is my message content:

```
Are you good @Daniel ?
```

I need to convert above message to following content:

```
Are you good <a href="#">@Daniel</a> ?
```

I use `react-router-dom`, so i need to replace link with this code:

**Eg:**

```
<Router>
   <Link to={ '#'} onClick={() => {this.example()}}>
    @Daniel
  </Link>
</Router>;
```

Comment: I edit demo link please refresh

Comment: The link is not working for me.

Comment: Please refresh. i edited link : https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-water-1e8uq 
also, demo:
https://1e8uq.codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 1):

It should be done with a string replace:

```js
// This is to have as tag "Are you good <a href="#">@Daniel</a> ?" (with @ in the username)
const replacementReg = /(@[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;
// This is to have as tag "Are you good <a href="#">Daniel</a> ?" (without @ in the username)
const replacementReg = /@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;

function decorateWithLink(text) {
   text.replace(replacementReg, replaced => `<a href="#"> ${replaced} </a>`);
}
```

and you should use in your component:

```js
this.setState(state => ({
    messages: [
        <li>{decorateWithLink(this.state.message)}</li>,
        ...state.messages
    ],
    message: '' // with this you don't need to call again the this.setState
}));
```

Comment: Thanks. but it has a bit of a problem. but i need this code for use on other component. very thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your submitMessage function here is the code:

```
submitMessage(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { message } = this.state;
        let msg = message.replace(/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, value => `<a href="#"> ${value} </a>`);
        this.setState(state => ({
          messages: [<li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: msg}} />, ...state.messages]
        }));
        this.setState({
          message: ""
        });
      }
```

here is the working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-platform-zmg94

Comment: now i want to try add Router instead of href. i think this will not easy

Comment: Best of luck for that 

Comment: No problem, I think I have to work on it for six months 
It was so interesting that even in Github I didn't see anyone have a project with this item. ‍

Comment: I would like to be one of its contributor  :))